# Json and Struct type unmatch

Tags: mongodb, go

Considering I have the following struct

```
type Product struct {
    Price int `json:"price" bson:"price"`
}
```

However, when I query an external API, the JSON comes in as a String.

```
[{ "price": "10000"}, { "price": "100"} ]
```

If i use `json.Unmarshal` it will fail because my struct is **integer** while the JSON is a string.

I set the price as **integer** because I need to store it in mongodb as integer.

Any solution to this mismatch type issues?

Comment: Implement separate structure with int price to save into DB. Convert Product to that struct by assigning every field.

Comment: End up i have to use 2 separate structs. One struct with the above suggested answer using `json:",string"` to insert into database, then one without the json line for querying database, so it will be sent to client in **int** instead of **string** when json encoded.